# Why do I get a "Identifier not found in PMC" error message when trying to convert a valid DOI that has a PMID?

Tags: medical, pubmed

I read on https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/30265128/:

- PMID: [30265128](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/30265128/) (PMID=[PubMed identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PubMed#PubMed_identifier))
- DOI: [10.1164/rccm.201806-1083IM](https://doi.org/10.1164/rccm.201806-1083IM)

However when trying to convert the DOI `10.1164/rccm.201806-1083IM` ot its PMID on https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/pmctopmid/ I get "Identifier not found in PMC":

[image]

Same issue with:

- PMID: [29794847](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/29794847/); DOI: 10.1097/SLA.0000000000002825
- PMID: [30601258](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/30601258/); DOI: 10.1097/SLA.0000000000003154
- PMID: [31725892](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/31725892/); DOI: 10.1093/eurheartj/ehz824

Why do I get a "Identifier not found in PMC" error message when trying to convert a valid DOI that has a PMID?

(Note that [DOI names are case insensitive](https://www.doi.org/doi_handbook/2_Numbering.html#2.4)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From understanding this is because these papers aren't in PMC but only in PubMed. Which raises the question: [How can I programmatically get the PMID from the DOI of a paper that isn't in PMC (i.e.. that doesn't have a PMCID)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63441023/395857)

---

Background reading: [PMID vs PMCID: What’s the Difference?](https://nexus.od.nih.gov/all/2015/08/31/pmid-vs-pmcid-whats-the-difference/)

> PubMed is an index of the biomedical literature. A PMID, also known as the PubMed reference number, is a number assigned by the NIH National Library of Medicine to papers indexed in PubMed. PubMed Central is an archive of full-text journal articles. The National Library of Medicine assigns a PMCID, also known as a PMC Identifier, to each full-text paper in PubMed Central.